# After using create-react-app to create a React app, is there a command to create the Redux part?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I think if we do

```
create-react-app hello-world
```

the app is only a React app but it doesn't have a Redux part to it.  Is there a command that will add the Redux part to it?

If not, are there a few standard steps to add Redux to it (for the current React 15.5.4 and Redux 3.6.0)?

Comment: `npm install --save redux react-redux` will add redux and the react-redux connector to the project. Then you just need to create a store with a rootReducer and use [the `Provider` from `react-redux`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store) at the root of the react app so that you can use `connect` for your redux-containers.

Comment: I was working with a React / Redux starter repo on github, and it already had `const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);` in it... and it was a 1 year old version... so it is a bit more complicated and I don't know what the current usage is if I want that and react-router, etc.  It would help if there is a standard command or a page that describe the current way to add the middleware, react-router... or maybe an official github repo for such a template

Comment: `redux` is not a standard react solution in any way. It is one of possible libraries, nothing more. Personally, I consider it the best, but it's just *a library*.

Answer (score 3):

Create React App only takes care of build configuration, and doesn't generate any code except a simple template to render a single component.

Adding Redux is not different from adding any other library. You run `npm install --save redux react-redux` (or `yarn add redux react-redux`) and then use the library.

If you want a complete example, check out the [Redux examples folder](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples). Most of them are built with Create React App so you can just use them as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I created tool for that purpose.

It's called wooo and you can check it on [github](http://github.com/kocisov/wooo).

It's really simple. You just need to install it globally.

```
npm install -g redux-wooo
```

And then in your CRA project folder, you run one command

```
wooo -d ./src
```

It will install needed dependencies and create basic redux files.